# Dynamically show/hide Elementor content based on URL parameters?

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, elementor

Elementor's docs mention [Dynamic Request Parameters](https://docs.elementor.com/article/451-dynamic-request-parameter), but I don't think they can be used to control visibility.

**I'm open to plugins, including paid solutions.**

I know this can be done via JavaScript, by checking query parameters and then setting class names, but this quickly gets out of control (it's what we do currently.)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Sadly no; we still rely on JavaScript to manage visibility.

Comment: interested as well if you find a solution

Answer (score 4):

Very late to this party but I was searching for the same thing then realised it was actually very easy with Elementor itself.

Set an element's CSS class dynamically, as a Get request parameter giving it the name you require - in the screenshot below I've just used "visibility". I've also set fallback (Advanced > Fallback) to "hide" and created a couple of CSS classes.

Now the element is visible with the URL parameter ?visibility=show otherwise it is hidden.

Not sure if this helps at all but it does the trick for me.

```
.hide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.show
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for this great solution. 

I was wondering how to frame this, if I only want to show when there are no parameters, such as on the homepage url but hide it when there is a parameter. The issue is for my case: url? postcode=(User input)

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to hide? If you're talking about widget, sections or columns you could use [JetEngine's Dynamic Visibility](https://crocoblock.com/knowledge-base/articles/jetengine-dynamic-visibility-module-options-overview/) module. That gives you the option to hide/show widgets based on parameters, query var, post and get are supported. See screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of Dynamic Visibility settings]

If you want to hide certain form fields based on these parameters, because the article you are referring to talks about forms, that may also be possible using the [JetEngine Forms](https://crocoblock.com/knowledge-base/articles/jetengine-conditional-visibility-rules-for-form-fields-overview/) module. I have an idea that might work if that is what you need. But if you just want to hide certain widgets than an explanation about that would be unnecessary, so let me know!